# How to control how points are displayed across different programs

Tags: shapefile, rendering

I'm completely new to GIS, but I'm trying to control how Points are displayed (shape, color, size, etc) across different programs (ArcGis, qGis, etc).

Is there a way to control the rendering of Points in a shapefile consistently in different GIS programs?

Comment: Interesting question! Probably no easy answer because shape files are not concerned with stylization. KML might be a more appropriate format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not between ArcGIS and QGIS. ArcGIS and QGIS each have their own methods for doing this: ArcGIS has .LYR files that can be used to store symbology, QGIS can take advantage of the Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) standard to do the same thing. But ArcGIS can't understand SLD (not on the Desktop anyway, I think the server version might), and QGIS can't understand .LYR files.

There are workarounds, these searches may help:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=qgis+lyr

https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=arcgis+sld

Comment: So perhaps a simple way would be to simply create a .lyr and a .lsd file with similar rendering directives both?

Comment: @jlmr That will definitely work. The only problem will be translating one format to the other.

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS v2 and greater you may use Nathan Woodrow [QGIS Layer Definitions](https://github.com/NathanW2/qgis-layer-definitions) plugin for saving and loading layer styles (.qlr).

Comment: those aren't portable though